# Is there a way to rename a TFS label?

Tags: tfs

Our code is branched in TFS along project lines, and each has its own separate build process

[image]

We label each project with the build number, e.g. Build_1, etc however I made the dumb mistake of forgetting that TFS labels must be unique and forgot to label my project with the name of the project.

To explain, I have labelled the P5624 folder four times with Build_1, Build_2, Build_3 & Build_4 when I should have used labels like P5624-Build_1, etc.

So, I am looking for a way to rename the labels. I couldn't find anything directly related on SO, and the microsoft Help on the TF Label command [(link here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ew32kd1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't give any indication that it can be done.

We don't do any automated builds or have anything that relies on a label name, so even if your solution is a "do it at your own risk" then I would still be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Renaming Labels is not supported by TFS. You can only create a new Label based on the old Label you want to remove.

If your are using Visual Studio, here are the steps how to do it

1. Right click the folder at Source Control Explorer to open
   ContextMenu and select 'Apply Label'
2. Change the Version-Combobox at the bottom to Label and find the old Label "P5624"
3. Name the new label "P5624-Build_1" and create it
4. Delete the old label if it isn't needed more.

Comment: Before I give it a go, do you know if this will work when I've already applied multiple labels to the project? (Ideally I want to rename all of them)

Comment: Sure, but you have to repeat the steps for each Label you want to "rename".

Comment: That worked perfectly. I wasn't aware that you could label an existing label. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately the date of the new label will be the current date, not the date of the old label, which may be confusing since VS sorts the labels by date.